# Unknown bar appears in Firefox 35 after update from 34. What is it?

Tags: firefox

Firefox version 35 upgraded from version 34.

[image: What is this Bar?]

What is this and how do I remove it?

Comment: It's something added by one of your add-ons. Disable them one by one until it goes away, and then go ask that add-on's author.

Comment: Also the bar can not be closed and includes two Icons one with hove tip saying menu on the left and the other with hover menu saying clear all. Neither do anything noticeable when used.